# Sending message back to Chrome extension from loaded iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I have a Chrome extension that users install on their browsers, when you open the extension popup (background page), all it does is loading a whole application back-end running on my server.

What I wanted to do is to have some kind of event emitter on my back-end application that can send message back to the chrome extension that is loaded this application.

I've tried this:

background.html:

```
<body>
    <iframe id="gateway" src="http://www.catchit.com"></iframe>
</body>
```

My back-end page for sending messages, say:

> **[www.catchit.com/message/send](http://www.catchit.com/message/send)**, which on click runs this:

```
var event = new CustomEvent(
    "newMessage",
    {
        detail: {
            users: users,
            message: message
        },
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false
    }
);

document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

My content script awaits this event:

```
document.addEventListener("newMessage", function(data) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data);
});
```

My background script as well:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    alert("message received" + message);
});
```

But of course it won't work... Since, the event is fired within iframe context ([www.servera.com](http://www.servera.com))

What am I missing here? I can't figure out how to throw a message back. That would be an awesome bridge between real application loaded within extension's popup and extension itself which can later dispatch messages to website opened on user browser.

Comment: Could [postmessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) solve your problem?

Comment: My problem would be that content script is not loaded on iframe.. And I'm not sure how to do it... I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what [gonzalovazzquez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2399921/gonzalovazzquez) said, I've made this solution:

Background.js:

```
// Listen for message from application (iframe)
top.window.addEventListener("message", function(message) {
    // Notify content-script about new message
});
```

My application javascript that is a part of iframe application:

```
top.window.postMessage({data: {users: users, message: message}}, "*");
return false;
```

From that point, you can tell your content script via background what to do on an actual page/tab, based on message received via application that is loaded within iframe on background.html